# Checkboxlist loop is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a dropdownlist control and a button in asp.net page. The dropdownlist is populated from a method. If I select any item other than the first item, after clicking the button, I lose the selected item in the DDL and it selects the first item and also I am getting the value of the first item only in the button click event. How can I fix the problem?

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="userDropDown" runat="server" DataTextField="CustomerName"  DataValueField="CustomerId">
</asp:DropDownList>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(!page.isPostBack)
{
    userDropDown.DataSource = CC.GetCustomers();
    userDropDown.DataBind();
}
}
```

Comment: Your code can't compile. `page` doesn't exist.

Comment: It should be `Page.IsPostBack` (check case sensitivity). Also note that it should not be within Button1_Click event as button click is always `Page.IsPostBack = true`. Use Page_Load method instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are binding your DropdownList to your datasource at ever request. Instead bind it only if `Page.IsPostBack` is false like below; (You may not need `ObjectDataSource`)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
     //bind your datasource here (something like below)
     userDropDown.DataSource = GetCustomers();
     userDropDown.DataBind();
   }
}
```

As soon as DataBind() method is called it will lose posted data of that object and the FirstItem will be selected by default.

Answer (score 2):

i think you must have bind `userDropDown` in `Page_Load` event without condition
 `if (!IsPostBack)`

Please put `dropdown binding part` inside  `if (!IsPostBack)`  condition then it should work

Answer (score 2):

Please bind dropdownlist values inside the if(!ispostback){} or
after submitting button please bind updated field to dropdownlistname.text