# NullReferenceException was unhandled

Tags: c#, lightswitch-2013

I'm just getting the hang of `Lightswitch`, but I keep getting the null reference exception error when I'm trying to find out if a selected item in a datagrid contains the letters "CMP". I look all over the place but I think I'm doing something wrong. Here is my code for reference:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.location.SelectedItem.locationID))
        {
            this.ShowMessageBox("test"); //not sure what to put there so I just made something up
        }
        else if (this.location.SelectedItem.locationID.Contains("CMP"))
        {
            this.FindControl("datePurchased").IsVisible = true;
            this.FindControl("age").IsVisible = true;
            this.FindControl("userList").IsVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
                this.FindControl("datePurchased").IsVisible = false;
                this.FindControl("age").IsVisible = false;
                this.FindControl("userList").IsVisible = false;
        }
```

I also tried

```
if(this.location.selecteditem.locationID != null)

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty)
```

but it always throws me the same error. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: probably your this.location.selecteditem variable or this.location is null

Comment: its a cell in a datagrid though, and there are some values there already. When I debugged it, it shows that there is a value, then all of a sudden it said its null.

Comment: i dont know how lightswitch works, but in asp.net if you select an item and dont keep it on postbacks, you cant reach them back, i think theres something like that in here.

Comment: sorry I'm still learning the ropes of programming...what do you mean by that? can you give me an example?

Comment: as i said i dont know lightswitch but, please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406795/dropdownlist-not-keeping-the-selected-item-after-postback)

Comment: What do you mean by "it said its null"? What said that *what* is null? What do you mean by "there is a value" - there is a value for *what*, exactly? What do you expect to happen if nothing is selected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: when i hover over the selecteditem part when i set a breakpoint, i get the popup saying "this.location.selecteditem | null"

Comment: hi nvoigt, yup i tried those. I tried != null = null == null and other checks stated on that post. Still throws me that exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guss `this.location` or `this.location.selecteditem` may be null, So you got that error.
So please try this `if` condition  instead of your `if` condition way

```
if(this.location != null && this.location.selecteditem !=null && this.location.selecteditem.locationID != null)
{
       //Write your code here 
}
```

So your final code look like

```
        if(this.location == null && this.location.selecteditem ==null && this.location.selecteditem.locationID == null)
        {
          this.ShowMessageBox("test"); //not sure what to put there so I just made something up
        }    

        else if (this.location.SelectedItem.locationID.Contains("CMP"))
        {
            this.FindControl("datePurchased").IsVisible = true;
            this.FindControl("age").IsVisible = true;
            this.FindControl("userList").IsVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
                this.FindControl("datePurchased").IsVisible = false;
                this.FindControl("age").IsVisible = false;
                this.FindControl("userList").IsVisible = false;
        }
```

Comment: awesome! it stopped throwing the exception...but now the code inside doesnt fire >.> but at least the exception is gone ^o^

Comment: Cool! I have updated my answer. Please take a look that, and please use break point for which values are threw null.

Comment: Thios is perfect its working now! thanks so much! I put the code in its own method and called it everytime the selection was changed and its works now! thanks so much!